# How to find out which getter methods are available

Tags: magento-1.9, magic-getter

Often I'm working on a Magento template or block and while looking for a variable I try to use a getter method.

I use xDebug so normally I just go through the debugger and find what I need and guess the getter method, and usually it works. for example:

```
$this->getProduct()->getId();
```

But sometimes I can't find the getter method and use xDebug with PHPStorm to evaluate the expression for the value I need.
[image]

This usually gives me an expression like the below:

```
$program['type']->_data['special_url_key']
```

While this works it does not seem to be the best way to do it, I've tried using `$program->getType();` but it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?  The example above is from a custom module, I thought with [Magento's Magic Getter & Setter methods](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/62068551774/magento-2-magic-getters-and-setters) it should still work.  Although, looking at this module the block in question inherits or extends from *Mage_Core_Block_Template*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$program` is neither an instance of `Varien_Object` nor an object at all, thus no [overloading methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) are available.

`$program['type']->getSpecialUrlKey()` might work if the array has an entry with the key `type` that is an instance of `Varien_Object`.

To make a developer's life easier, classes that offer "magic" methods should be annotated accordingly, see [`Mage_Sales_Model_Order`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L27) for example.